# Custom queries in django serializers

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have the following view that allows me to determine defined prices for the logged in user and captures the information of the provider model requested by the user:

```
class ProductStoDists(mixins.ListModelMixin, generics.GenericAPIView):
       permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,IsSavedRole)
       queryset = SellProduct.objects.select_related("provider", "product", "coupon_percentage", "coupon_quality").filter(~Q(stock = None), Q(disabled_sale=False))
       serializer_class = SellProductSerializer
       parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,)
       filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, filters.SearchFilter]
       filterset_fields = ["product", "provider", "provider__state_prin_venue", "product__sectors", "product__categories", "provider__type_provider"]
       pagination_class = Pagination

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)

#@method_decorator(cache_page(60*60))
#@method_decorator(vary_on_cookie)
def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
    page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
    entity = Provider.objects.filter(administrator=request.user)
    data_price = []
    if page is not None:
        serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
        object_dataset = DataSetIds()
        if request.user.role != "lab":
            prices = []
            for sell_product_cost in serializer.data:
                provider = Provider.objects.filter(id_provider=sell_product_cost["provider"]).select_related("country_prin_venue", "state_prin_venue", "city_prin_venue", "administrator")
                price_object = CustomPrices(entity, request.user.id, provider)
                if provider[0].type_provider == "dist":
                    if request.user.role == "dist" or request.user.role == "sto":
                        sell_product_cost["distributors"] = price_object.get_sell_distributors(sell_product_cost["id_sell"])
                    else:
                        sell_product_cost["distributors"] = None
                else:
                    if request.user.role == "sto":
                        sell_product_cost["storage"] = price_object.get_sell_storage(sell_product_cost["id_sell"])
                    else:
                        sell_product_cost["storage"] = None

        return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
    serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

How could I make the "storage" or distributors field be done from the serializardor and not from the view?, since I consider that this can slow down the response of the customer service.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your model definitions, the answer likely involves performing this work at the SQL builder level rather than after querying the data. If you can't, then this points to an architectural problem that limits the abilities of your application.

For example let's say your `SellProduct` model has a foreign key to `Provider`. If you need to conditionally add information to the queryset then you can do so using `annotate` and `Case`

```
queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
queryset = queryset.select_related('provider') \
                   .annotate(
                     distributors=Case(
                       When(provider__type_provider='dist', then=Value('foo')),
                       default=Value('other foo'),
                       output_field=CharField()
                   )
```

But if you're relying on python methods to fill in bits of information *for each* instance returned from the queryset then you need to re-assess your model structure and determine if you can better relate information to avoid this situation.